# Deleting a row in DataGridView on rowLeave

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView in a vb.net form, not connected to any source. I want to remove a row when the user pass to another row or focus out the DGV. The row should be removed if there's an empty cell in it.

That's my code:

```
Private Sub dgvSpSettings_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSpSettings.RowLeave
    If e.RowIndex < (dgvSpSettings.Rows.Count - 1) Then 'Esclude l'ultima riga dal controllo sulle righe vuote
        If Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value Is Nothing OrElse Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = "" OrElse Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing OrElse Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString() = "" Then
            Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This doesn't work because I can't perform the method `Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)` in this event. I tried to store the row in a private var and then delete it in other events (like click), but the result is not what I expected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my final solution. It works for me and I hope it's conceptually correct. I used delegates and *Leave* + *LostFocus* events.

```
'**********
'* Controllo righe da eliminare
'**********
Private Sub dgvSpSettings_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSpSettings.RowLeave
    Me.dgvSpSettings.CommitEdit(0)

    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    For Each cell In row.Cells
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
    Next

    If Not row.IsNewRow() Then 'Esclude l'ultima riga dal controllo sulle righe vuote
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells(0).Value) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells(1).Value) Then
            _rowBlank = row
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Delegate Sub setCurrentCellDelegate()

Private Sub setCurrentCell()
    For Each cell In _rowBlank.Cells
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
    Next

    Me.dgvSpSettings.CurrentCell = _rowBlank.Cells(0)
    Me.dgvSpSettings.BeginEdit(True)
    _rowBlank = Nothing
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub removeRowDelegate()

Private Sub removeRow()
    Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows.Remove(_rowBlank)
    _rowBlank = Nothing
    _rowBlankDeleting = False
End Sub

'**********
'* Controllo righe da eliminare
'**********
Private Sub dgvSpSettings_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvSpSettings.Leave
    If _rowBlank IsNot Nothing AndAlso _rowBlankDeleting = False Then
        If MsgBox("Alcuni campi della riga non sono stati valorizzati. Eliminare la riga?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Eliminare") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            _rowBlankDeleting = True
            Me.dgvSpSettings.BeginInvoke(New removeRowDelegate(AddressOf removeRow))
        Else
            Me.dgvSpSettings.BeginInvoke(New setCurrentCellDelegate(AddressOf setCurrentCell))
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'**********
'* Controllo righe da eliminare
'**********
Private Sub dgvSpSettings_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvSpSettings.LostFocus
    If _rowBlank IsNot Nothing AndAlso _rowBlank IsNot Me.dgvSpSettings.CurrentRow AndAlso _rowBlankDeleting = False Then
        If MsgBox("Alcuni campi della riga non sono stati valorizzati. Eliminare la riga?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Eliminare") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            _rowBlankDeleting = True
            Me.dgvSpSettings.BeginInvoke(New removeRowDelegate(AddressOf removeRow))
        Else
            Me.dgvSpSettings.BeginInvoke(New setCurrentCellDelegate(AddressOf setCurrentCell))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the best possible solution but atleast I've come up with something that might work for you. Basically you set the row to read only instead of deleting it. And since paint is called when you leave the row you can put the deletion code in paint instead.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave
    DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    If e.RowIndex < (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) Then
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value Is Nothing OrElse _
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = "" OrElse _
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing OrElse _
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString() = "" Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i <> DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).ReadOnly Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
            If i = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                Exit While
            End If
        Else
            i += 1
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've found a better solution (for my needs).

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the row in the RowLeave event handling because it is "busy".
A solution for this type of cases that I sometimes apply is to invoke the application.Idle event (I do not really like it, because it feels clumsy, but it works well):

```
  Private Sub dgvSpSettings_RowLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSpSettings.RowLeave
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value Is Nothing OrElse
      e.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = "" OrElse   
      Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing OrElse 
      Me.dgvSpSettings.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value.ToString() = "" Then

      Me._rowToDelete = row
      AddHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf AppIdle
    End If
  End Sub

  Private _rowToDelete As DataGridViewRow

  Private Sub AppIdle(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Me._rowToDelete IsNot Nothing Then
      dgvSpSettings.Rows.Remove(Me._rowToDelete)
      Me._rowToDelete = Nothing
    End If
    RemoveHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf AppIdle
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is quite good. But I've found a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is that you can't delete from the bottom  up (1, 2. 3, etc) you have to go from top to bottom (3, 2, 1) like this:

```
For j = DataGrid1.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
   DataGrid1.Rows.RemoveAt(j)
Next
```

The problem is that VB considers the first row to be the row that doesn't contain any data (the empty one you can enter information into.) This one worked for me.